# Windows 10 Installation has failed

Tags: windows-10, installation

When I'm installing Windows 10 it doesn't detect any problems, the installation were very smooth, but when the installation is done and says "Your PC will restart a few times" the Windows 10 installation then aborts and shows:

**Windows 10 installation has failed**

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: We're going to need a little more detail. What OS is your system currently running? Are you trying to upgrade from Windows 7/8, a feature update for Windows 10, or a clean install? Are you running any disk encryption software? What make and model is your system? There may be log files that could be of use, but we need to know more about your setup before we can help.

Comment: I'm currently Running Windows 7 SP1, i just use the media creation tool from microsoft to upgrade my pc, and i don't run any encryption software, and my pc is 32-bit, but where is the log files stored?

Comment: A good place to start may be `setuperr.log`, found in `C:\Windows\Panther`, but before that, just to rule it out, since your system is 32-bit, you are sure that you have the 32-bit installer, right? :) More details on the log files can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolve-windows-10-upgrade-errors#log-files), if you want to browse  through it.

Comment: Yes, i choose the 32-bit installer and when i open the setuperr.log it shows nothing

Comment: Found Some Errors in $Windows.~WS Folder :

Comment: The first error is about CInstallUI::GetDefaultLanguage(1785): Result = 0x80070002[gle=0x00000002]

Comment: The second Error is about : CSystemHelper::CheckConnectedStandby(642): Result = 0x80070057

Comment: Third Error : CSetupManager::GetDUSetupResults(5499): Result = 0x80070490

Comment: Then shows 4 same errors like this

Comment: CDlpTask::Cancel(979): Result = 0xC1800104

Comment: @mitch002 Ultimate step: backup your data, wipe system partition (C: drive), install OS.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error messages from the log file. Comments will get cleaned up and the question needs this additional detail.

Comment: You indicate the problem is solved by accepting an answer. Please don't use title for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Option **"Save programs and user files** (idk the name) To **Save User files only**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please confirm your computer can support Windows 10.

You can run Windows 10 Update Assistant to check if it's compatible.

Then do the following steps:

**Step 1: Use System File Checker to repair damaged Windows files**

1. Open an elevated command prompt.
2. Run the "**sfc /scannow**" command.
3. Try to install Windows 10 again.

**Step 2: Run the System Update Readiness tool**

If the problem continues, use the [System Update Readiness tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness) to fix Windows corruption errors.